# How do I create users which are added to my db if i already have my schema done?

Tags: mongoose, mean-stack, meanjs, mean.io, mongoose-schema

### I have this as a file in ./models

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var user_sch = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String, 
        user_name: String,
        password: String
    });
    var user = mongoose.model('User', user_sch);
    module.exports = user;
```

I was wondering how I would go forward in being able to create users to add to my database if I have a page that has a sign up form.

I know what I have to do is related to a function in server.js and probably something else but I don't know and haven't found anything to help.

Anything is appreciated!

Edit: I have looked at this but can't figure out what/where he is adding things from the signup form to the db or what the difference is when using mongoose vs mongo.
http://code.runnable.com/U108R8ihwn4m4TM5/user-creation-signup-and-login-with-express-4-and-mongodb-for-node-js

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using MeanJS looking at the tags.

In your controller server side you include the model like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');
```

And then in your request or where you handle the user data:

```
  var user = new User(req.body);
  user.save(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
  });
  } else {
    res.jsonp(user);
   }
  });
```

This will save the user data into the database. Go to the MeanJS website and download the latest version from github. The default 'template' has examples of doing these kind of stuff. Good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

for anybody looking to achieve the following ::

1. Creating a signup form using html5 / bootstrap /css3
2. Writing backend using nodejs [ express framework ]
3. Using mongodb as data store

I would highly recommend reading the following article which I found to be very useful. You also learn to store your password securely using HMAC.

[Signup using nodejs express mongodb](https://www.nodejsera.com/nodejs-tutorial-day13-signup-using-nodejs-express-mongodb.html)